# How To Init Abstract Class Object in Kotlin Like JAVA

Tags: java, android, kotlin, generics, abstract

I am New in kotlin, just shift from android/java to android/kotlin. Kotlin is really an easy language but somewhere its support is not enough or its suggestion does not work.
I am writing a code in which I will call a generic abstract class which have parametric constructor. the generic class is written in Java and I can init that class from java class without any error but when I init generic class from kotlin it gives type mismatch error.

1st let me show you my java code without errors

```
GenericAdapter<String, NotificationFragmentBinding> transmissionAdapter;
   transmissionAdapter = new GenericAdapter<String, NotificationFragmentBinding>(getContext(),carsList) {
        @Override
        public int getLayoutResId() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindData(String model, int position, NotificationFragmentBinding dataBinding) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(String model, int position) {

        }
    }
```

Now Let me show you my kotlin code with error

```
 var notificationGenericAdapter: GenericAdapter<String, NotificationFragmentBinding>? = null
notificationGenericAdapter = object : GenericAdapter<String?, NotificationFragmentBinding?>(this, list) {
        override fun getLayoutResId(): Int {
            return 0
        }

        override fun onBindData(model: String?, position: Int, dataBinding: NotificationFragmentBinding?) {}
        override fun onItemClick(model: String?, position: Int) {}
    }
```

The Kotlin Code gives me Type mismatch error.

Comment: `String` and `String?` is different types. Use single type for `GenericAdapter<String, NotificationFragmentBinding>? = null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Stanislav Bondar

That was a Foolish mistake

The correct version is here bellow

```
notificationGenericAdapter = object : GenericAdapter<String, NotificationFragmentBinding>(this, list) {
    override fun getLayoutResId(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    override fun onBindData(model: String?, position: Int, dataBinding: NotificationFragmentBinding?) {}
    override fun onItemClick(model: String?, position: Int) {}
}
```

There was error of String and String? I was using String? but when I assign I was using String without null check